# How to get Router Name & IP as shown in Windows Network Tab? (in Code or from Registry)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, networking

Basically, if you go to Start and click Computer and then click on the Network link on the left hand side, you'll notice on the right hand side several categories, one of which is titled "Network Infrustructure", in that category, my router is listed, and in my case, it is "LINKSYS WAG160N Wireless-N ADSL2+ Gateway" and when you right-click and select properties, it lists basic info such as internal/gateway IP address, on mine it is "192.168.1.1"

I would like to know how to retreive this information in ie: either registry location or Windows API call or .net framework reference etc, preferably a Windows API or Registry Location so that i can call it using a legacy VB6 app but anything will do at the moment as i am totally lost in this respect.

thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is provided from the Universal Plug-n-Play (UPnP) service running on your router.  Windows has a [UPnP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382303(v=VS.85).aspx) you should be able to use to query the device.  Specifically the [IUPnPDevice interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381561(v=VS.85).aspx) has the FriendlyName and PresentationURL properties, which should give you the name the IP you're talking about.

Comment: this was perfect and i am now where i want to be in my research. thank you so much.